# Generics open and closed constructed types

Tags: c#, generics

Recently I noticed that generic constructed types can be open and closed. But I do not understand what they actually mean. Can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In practice the terminology doesn't really matter much - I can't remember the last time I had to worry about it *except* when trying to write about it.

- An *unbound* type has no type arguments specified
- A *constructed* type has at least one type argument specified
- A type parameter is an *open type*
- An array type where the element type is open is an *open type*
- An *open* constructed type has at least one type argument which is an open type
- A *closed* type is any type which isn't open

(There are further rules for nested types. Consult the C# 3.0 spec section 4.4 for gory details.)

As an example of an open constructed type, consider:

```
public class NameDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string, T>
```

The base class of `typeof(NameDictionary<>)` is:

- Constructed because it specifies type arguments
- Open because the second type argument (`T`) is an open type

The MSDN docs for [`Type.IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) have quite a useful little table.

Just to reiterate, this is almost entirely unimportant in day to day use.

I'm generally in favour of knowing the correct terminology - particularly for things like "pass by reference" etc - but in this case it really, really doesn't come up very often. I would like to actively discourage you from worrying about it :)

Comment: Now a days most interview questions i faced are asked from your book.So for clarification purpose i asked. :) .

Comment: @generixs: If someone asked me that in an interview, I would confess that I wouldn't be able to say without consulting a book or the spec :) Not a very useful interview question, I have to say.

Comment: :) give me a portion of your brain ,so that i can answer as if i were a Jon Skeet ..(sorry for kidding..).

Comment: So in summary : if  we find any type arguments then its a bound/constructed type (otherwise its unbound) and if we find any type parameters then its an open type (otherwise its closed). A closed type cannot be unbound. Did I leave any big ones out ?

Comment: @mumtaz: I'm afraid I'm too sleepy to say for sure. Basically I've *never* fully got my head round this terminology.

Comment: @Jon ... lolz... that was actually a great response. The more I read about them the more I feel like they were never intended for human consumption in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet, How would you describe the relationship between `List<>` and `List<int>`? Is the latter a closed subtype of the former? A closed version of? A closed type of?

Comment: @FireLizzard: I'd probably say it's a closed constructed type, constructed from the unbound type `List<T>`. That's if I really had to say anything - I try hard not to talk about terminology like this.

Comment: I was reading your "C# in depth", and faced this "open and closed constructed type" term. I have decided to read more about this at StackOverflow, and finally I have found this answer here :)

Comment: "C# in Depth" says that unbound type is *the form of a generic type where none of the type parameters have been provided with
type arguments*. So for given type parameters `K` and `V` is `Dictionary<K, V>` is an unbound type or only `Dictionary<,>` is unbound?

Comment: @saidfagan: I'm not sure what you mean by "for given type parameters K and V". I'd need really specific context to give an answer here - and I could be wrong, frankly. As noted in the answer, this is very rarely useful. We've even been trying to remove some of it in the ECMA spec.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean If we are writing code inside some generic class with type parameters of `K` and `V` will `Dictionary<K,V>` be unbound? Or only `Dictionary<,>` is considered an unbound type? I know these terms are unimportant, but will be good to understand them.

Comment: @saidfagan: It's an open constructed type - see bullets 2, 3 and 5 in the first list.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, but is it bound or unbound? or neither of them?

Comment: @saidfagan: It's constructed, not unbound. (Those are opposites - see the first two bullets.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for being intrusive, but if `constructed` and `unbound` are opposites, what is the place of `bound` types between these two?

Comment: @saidfagan: I don't think I've referred to "bound types" anywhere here. But really, I think this has gone far enough in comments. If there are further questions, please ask in a new post - but again, it's *really* not important in 99.999% of development.

Answer (score 11):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334.aspx):

> A generic type or method is closed if instantiable types have been substituted for all its type parameters, including all the type parameters of all enclosing types. You can only create an instance of a generic type if it is closed.

So this works as `List<int>` is **closed**:

```
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<int>));
```

But this throws an exception at run-time because `List<>` is **open**:

```
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>));
                                               ↑
```

Comment: In that case it's an unbound type as well though - an open, constructed type is the more esoteric kind :)

Answer (score 4):

I have mostly used open generics (basically uninstantiated generics) in dependency injection mappings. For example, something like

```
Bind<IRepository<>>()
   .To<BasicRepository<>>()
```

Then, when my object constructor contains:

```
public SomethingController(IRepository<Something>) { ... }
```

My dependency injection mechanism will instantiate a BasicRepository< Something > automagically. (This works with Ninject and StructureMap, and probably the Castle Windsor library; I'm not sure about other frameworks).

Comment: `Autofac` also supports open generic types: [Autofac - creating components](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation#Open_Generic_Types)

Comment: As does [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#registration-of-open-generic-types)