# C# Covariance puzzle, i encountered

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I just encountered an interesting Problem concerning Generics and covariance and, long story short, spent 30 minutes trying to declare a Type until i gave up.

For clarity: I already have a workaround for this, and do not need help with my project currently. I just asked this question because i am a fan of perversely complicated generic types. If you are too, enjoy.

I was trying to define this method to fetch a global `IDictionary`, that manages all objects of type `T` by their IDs. (IDs are only unique among objects of the same type).

```
IDictionary<int, T> getCache<T>() where T : BaseClass { }
```

To avoid checking `T` for every derivative of `BaseClass` (of which there are many) i wanted to define a global Dictionary of Dictionaries, to look up the correct List.

I tried something like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, IDictionary<int, Baseclass>> allCaches;
```

Expierienced users of Generics might see the problem with this implementation: the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface is not covariant.

(Not covariant means, `IDictionary<int, DerivedClass>` does NOT inherit from `IDictionary<int, BaseClass>`. As a result, objects of the former type cannot be placed in my Dictionary `allCaches`)

I ended up, just using an `IDictionary<int, BaseClass>` for all my caches, and manually cast back the stored elements when i read them.

I wonder, can anyone think of an implementation for my method `getCache<T>()` that uses minimal casting and does not manually branch for all types derived from `BaseClass`?

Comment: I think you'd need dependent types to do this without casting, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generic static type as substitute for a`Dictionary<Type,T>` provided I can live with those caches being singletons.

```
public static class Caches
{
    public static class For<T>
    {
        public static IDictionary<int,T> Cache{get;}=new Dictionary<int,T>(); 
    }

    public static Set<T>(int key,T value)=> For<T>.Cache[k]=v;
}

// and to use the dictionary
public void DoStuff(int i, string value){
    Caches.For<string>.Cache[i]=value;
    // or if you define generic methods in Caches like Set 
    Caches.Set(i,value);
}
```

Remember that `Class<int>` and `Class<float>` are two distinct types who share the same generic type definition `Class<T>`.

There is no runtime type such as `Class<T>` as it is an Open Generic Type whereas `Class<int>` and `Class<float>` are Closed Generic Types as explained in [Tony The Pony's SO answer on Open and Closed Generic Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

This is why static members of `Class<float>` and `Class<int>` are distinct, those are two distinct classes that redefine all their members each time the generic parameter changes.

Comment: I can't use singletons for my particular problem, but might use it for other parts of my project. Definitely didn't think of that, thanks for the sugggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to just ignore the type for the value in your 'dictionary of caches' and cast it on return:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> allCaches = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public IDictionary<int, T> GetCache<T>() where T : BaseClass
{
    object cache;

    if (!allCaches.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out cache))
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        allCaches.Add(typeof(T), cache);
    }

    return (IDictionary<int, T>) cache;
}
```