# Meanings of constructed types, bounded types and unbounded types?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

From C# 5.0 Specifications

> **4.4 Constructed types**
>
> A generic type declaration, by itself, denotes **an unbound generic
> type** that is used as a “blueprint” to form  many different types, by
> way of applying type arguments. The type arguments are written within
> angle brackets  (< and >) immediately following the name of the
> generic type.  An unbound generic type can only be used within a
> typeof-expression (§7.6.11).   A type that includes at least one type
> argument is  called **a constructed type**. A constructed type can be
> used in most places in the language in which a type name  can appear.
> An unbound generic type can only be used within a typeof-expression
> (§7.6.11).
> **Constructed types** can also be used in expressions as simple names (§7.6.2) or when accessing a member  (§7.6.4).

Is the concept of "constructed type" the same as the concept of "bounded generic type"?

> **4.4.3 Bound and unbound types**
>
> The term **unbound type** refers to a non-generic type or an unbound
> generic type. The term **bound type** refers to a non-generic type or a
> constructed type.
>
> **An unbound type** refers to the entity declared by a
> type declaration. **An unbound generic type** is not itself a type,  and
> cannot be used as the type of a variable, argument or return value, or
> as a base type. The only construct in  which an unbound generic type
> can be referenced is the typeof expression (§7.6.11).

Is a non-generic type both an unbound and bound type?

Comment: A nice (related) summary from Jon Skeet here too http://stackoverflow.com/a/1735060/1663001

Answer (score 5):

> Is the concept of "constructed type" the same as the concept of "bounded generic type"?

Yes, modulo your typo. You meant to say "bound generic type", not "bounded generic type".

> Is a non-generic type both an unbound and bound type?

Yes.

> Why are the terms so redundant/duplicate/convoluted?

The terms were invented for the convenience of the specification authors and the compiler team. The only redundancy you've identified is that *constructed* is equal to *bound generic*, which seems pretty reasonable to me. I don't see any duplication or convolution.

If these terms seem complicated, well then I submit to you that *type theory of modern line-of-business OO languages is a complicated subject*; its jargon reflects that complexity.

It might help to think about it this way. Suppose we have a class C that takes n type arguments, for n >= 0:

- The concept *C-that-takes-n-type-arguments* is an *unbound* type.
- The concept *C-with-n-type-arguments* is a *bound* type.
- A *bound generic type* must be a generic type that has been *constructed with type arguments*, so we call it a *constructed type*.

Plainly if n == 0 then C is both a bound and an unbound type at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Why are the terms so redundant/duplicate/convoluted?