# Why does IsGenericTypeDefinition return false?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to understand `IsGenericTypeDefinition` property of Type. As I understand, it is just class template without any substituted types (and we cannot create instance of this class). Here is code of my test program:

```
class Test
{
    public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyList<>).GetMethod("Add").DeclaringType.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
    }
}
```

Why does program print `false` ? I just get this method info from generic type definition. Why does it have not generic declaring type definition? Is it bug?

Comment: Maybe because Add metho isn't generic but the class List<T> is. Add method just use the generic parameter type as parameter but the method itself doesn't define it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `DeclaringType` in this case is the instantiation of `List<>` for the generic type parameter `T` belonging to `MyList<T>`.

To get the un-instantiated generic type you need to use `GetGenericTypeDefinition` that will return `List<>`

```
typeof(MyList<>).GetMethod("Add").DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

Drilling in a bit deeper we get:

```
var instantiationListArgs = typeof(MyList<>).GetMethod("Add").DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments();
var myListArg = typeof(MyList<>).GetGenericArguments();
var listArgs = typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments();
Console.WriteLine(myListArg[0] == instantiationListArgs[0]); // Will output true, List was instantiated for the T in MyList
Console.WriteLine(listArgs[0] == instantiationListArgs[0]); // Will be false. The generic argument is different then the T in the free List<>
```

Comment: It seems strange for me. I thought that List<T> is too generic type defintion. Now it turns out that it is not

Comment: @LmTinyToon Added some more code, maybe it clears it up a bit, you can't inherit an un-instantiated generic, you can inherit `List<object>` for example, In your case the instantiation just happens to be for another generic parameter

Comment: There is no need to involve methods at all - the following holds `typeof(MyList<>).BaseType != typeof(List<>)`. Basically the question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types

Comment: @IvanStoev Very true about `typeof(MyList<>).BaseType != typeof(List<>)` and it is a duplicate of the question you indicate as far as content is concerned. Same basic idea, but the question I believe still has value, searching for this specific case you would never hit upon the referenced question, someone might hit upon this one

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Sure. That's why I'm commenting rather than dupe-hammering it :)