# How to do generic polymorphism on open types in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have an interface like:

```
interface IFoo<in T> {
   ...
}
```

And I want to have a collection of those classes **WITHOUT** forcing a specific generic parameter for all collection elements, like:

```
class IFooCollection {
   List<IFoo<?>> _items;

   public IFooCollection(List<IFoo<?>> items)
   {
        _items = items;
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: You'd need to make it a list of `object`.

Comment: This is what I have now, but I was thinking about if it's possible to force at least the IFoo<>

Comment: If you want to force the IFoo, then user Iv has posted a good answer.

Comment: Do you want to do generic polymorphism on open types of `IFoo<>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want to force a specific type, make an `abstract class` or an `interface` this way:

```cs
interface IFoo { }
```

And inherit it in your type-specific Foo (with generic parameters), like:

```cs
interface IFoo<T> : IFoo {}
```

This way you can just have a `List<IFoo>` and add `IFoo<T>` instead.

More examples:

```cs
class FooCollection {
    private List<IFoo> _collection;

    public FooCollection()
    {
        _collection = new List<IFoo>();
    }

    public void Add(IFoo foo)
    {
        _collection.Add(foo);
    }

    public void Remove(IFoo foo)
    {
        _collection.Remove(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the T dynamic

Comment: So you want a list of different types? Like IFoo<int> and IFoo<string> in one list?

Comment: correct, are not scalars, but are different object classes. I would iterate the list and get the type to the object and decide what to do with it

Comment: thanks for the response, I was thinking about something like that, then we don't have anything like <?> , <>, <dynamic>, whatever that I can use? Is this the only way?

Comment: @fj123x `we don't have anything like <?>` Yes we do; the type is called `object`.

Comment: This is the only way from what I know. You, probably, could use dynamics but that would be quite weird and just unreadable I guess, not understandable and you won't be able to force inheritance from IFoo.

Comment: ok, I would wait some minutes to check if there are any other solutions, if not, I will approve the answer. Thanks!

Comment: There is no other solution in C# and in .NET yet, as I know. The CLR does not supporty generic polymorphism on open types.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @IvMisticos, to be able to do pseudo generic polymorphism on open type, you can write:

```
interface IFoo
{
}

interface IFoo<in T> : IFoo
{

}

class FooCollection 
{
  List<IFoo> _items;

  public FooCollection(List<IFoo> items)
  {
    _items = items;
  }
}

var item1 = some instance of IFoo<int>;
var item2 = some instance of IFoo<double>;
var item3 = some instance of IFoo<string>;

var list = new List<IFoo> { item1, item2, item3 };

var col = new FooCollection(list);
```

Since there is no diamond operator `<>` to allow true generic polymorphism on open types in C#, it is the only thing you can do, as I know.

I really dislike this hack that smells bad.

[What exactly is an "open generic type" in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net)

[Generics -Open and closed constructed Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

Comment: Question author doesn't want to force a type for a collection, you misunderstood the question and I did, but I gave a correct answer. You may mark it as useful and delete your own if you want.

Comment: I perhaps understand what the OP ask for. Answer updated.

Comment: okay, so basically you just extended my answer :( dont try to take over what i did