# C# Generic type of a class that require a generic type

Tags: c#, class, generics, types

got actually a problem, I need to store a list of a class that need a generic type, but when inherited and generic type defined on a subclass, I can't add this subclass to the list anymore.
Let me show you :

```
public class Foo<T>
{

}

public class Foo2 : Foo<int>
{

}

List<Foo<object>> objects = new List<Foo<object>>();
objects.Add(new Foo2()); // <----- This isn't working
```

What is the way to do this ?
Thanks for your time

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to achieve that. This is because the class implements `Foo<int>` and not `Foo<object>`,  inheritance happens on level of `Foo<>` not `T`. Maybe those classes could have a common interface instead? Something like `Foo<T> : ISomething` ?

Comment: So the only way to do this is to remove generic type and casting it ?

Comment: In short - you can't.  In some cases something similar would be achievable with [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) and interfaces (though `Foo2` should be `Foo` of some reference type, not value type).

Comment: That's not that stupid, I think i'm gonna use an interface that will be the best idea, thanks ! :D

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c/58247676#58247676