# c# Base class to unknown generic class

Tags: c#

Having following class structure, how can I get instance of `Configuration<X>` where class `X` is not known at the build time?

Initial setup:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
}

public class Configuration<T> : IConfiguration
{
}


List<IConfiguration> configList;

configList.Add( new Configuration<X>());
configList.Add( new Configuration<Y>());
configList.Add( new Configuration<Z>());




     Foreach(var config in configList)
{
   Proccess(config) // errors .  I need to cast in here
}

Proccess<T>(Configuration<T>) {}
```

Boxing or reflection is allowed. I need to cast base class to unknown generic type class.

Comment: but I dont know type in compile time. I need to cast in rune time

Comment: What would you want to do *after* casting to it? You can't know any of the members at compile-time, if you don't know the type at compile-time...

Comment: _"but I dont know type in compile time. I need to cast in rune time"_ please give an example that shows your problem. The given code shoud work just fine (given you actually instantiate the list before adding to it).

Comment: Ah, wait. `X` is unknown at compile-time?? I guess then Generics is not the correct tool.

Comment: Maybe you need instantiate the collection : `List<IConfiguration> configList =  new List<IConfiguration>();`

Comment: Your example still doesn't describe what you want to _do_ with `result`, after having hypothetically being able to cast it to Configuration<X> for an unknown value of X

Comment: @vernou That's missing in the snippet, but I think OP's actual problem is the unknown type of `X` at compile time. ( i.e. `new Configuration<FigureOutAtRuntime>()` )

Comment: Maybe you can move the method `Process` in the interface `IConfiguration`.

Comment: The method `Process()` is unclear. Passing in `IConfiguration` as parameter to the method might also be an option.

Comment: This just seems to move the problem a step. If you don't know X at compile time, how can Process ...process it?

Comment: proccess do same thing for all. but in proccess I need to use type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase/) and [How to create List of open generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt) and [How to do generic polymorphism on open types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c/) and [What is polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used)

Comment: I think you probably want to constrain `T` like this `public class Configuration<T> : IConfiguration where T : IProcessable` and that interface would have functions that allow you to process. Now you can consider every `T` to also be `IProcessable`

Comment: What is the actual purpose? What is it that you are trying to do? The only way to work with types that are not known at compile time is thru reflection, and that is cumbersome and slow.