# Storing classes with generic types in a single array

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `Validator<T>` and a multitude of other classes that inherit from it like: `TagValidator : Validator<Tag>`.

Let's say I want to make a single `ModelValidator` class that stores all the classes that inherit from `Validator<T>` and runs a specific one when I do `ModelValidator.Validate<T>(T model)`

Is there a way to store classes with a generic type in a single array or perhaps a dictionary?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] so we can see the two different things you are trying to store.

Comment: You can define a non-generic base class `Validator`, then have a `Dictionary<Type, Validator>` and do `(Validator<T>)dict[typeof(T)]`. Or loop through an array of type `Validator[]` testing for `is Validator<T>`. Or give your `Validator` class a `TryValidate(object)` method, and try the validation with all validators

Comment: What IoC container are you using?

Comment: @canton7 The issue is, The 'Validator<T>' class isn't mine, it's actually AbstractValidator<T> from FluentValidator nuget package.

Comment: @JCode `AbstractValidator<T>` implements `IValidator<T>` implements `IValidator`, so `IValidator` is your non-generic base type. `IValidator` has some [useful methods you could use](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/ab60c9d41c4d63322f7d7ba1fdffd6606bbd5d81/src/FluentValidation/IValidator.cs#L57)

Comment: Quite obviously you can use `object[]` to store a list of any object - is there a reason that you don't want to use that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create List of open generic type of class<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247604/how-to-do-generic-polymorphism-on-open-types-in-c/58247676#58247676 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592905/c-sharp-downcasting-generic-object-with-derived-interfaces-to-the-base-interfa/ & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964/c-sharp-generic-inheritance-and-covariance-part-2/14264436#14264436 &

Comment: @canton7 using IValidator as the type of my array would limit functionality I can use greatly. Also I can't store `TagValidator` as `IValidator` unless I inherit from it directly.

@OlivierRogier no, it's related but not quite.

@Enigmativity boxing/unboxing, packing/unpacking.

Comment: @JCode You missed the point of my earlier comment. You can *cast* it to an `IValidator<T>` / `AbstractValidator<T>`

Comment: @canton7 But that wouldn't work, because I have to define rules by creating `TagValidator` that inherits from `AbstractValidator<Tag>` - if I cast back and forth, I'll lose the applied rules.

Comment: @JCode Why would you lose the rules?

Comment: @canton7 Because they're applied on constructor, if I store just instances of AbstractValidator<Tag> as opposed to class inheriting from it, it'll only run constructor for AbstractValidator, then casting to TagValidator won't re-run the constructor.

Comment: @JCode `AbstractValidator<Tag> validator = new TagValidator()` will run `TagValidator`'s constructor. Note that `AbstractValidator<T>` is *abstract*: you can't create an instance of it directly anyway, you *have* to create an instance of a subclass

Comment: @canton7 but I can't store AbstractValidator<Tag> in a list that isn't for AbstractValidator<Tag>, since I can't just use List<AbstractValidator<T>>

Comment: @JCode Yes, we discussed that already. `List<IValidator> list` then `list.Add(new TagValidator())` for example

Comment: @canton7 I'll try that, thought I've tried previously and I couldn't use any functionality without casting. I should say in advance that I'm trying to avoid casting.

Comment: @JCode We discussed that already as well: you're going to have to cast. See Enigmativity's answer

Comment: @canton7 Hmm, okay, hope the performance-loss isn't too severe.

Comment: Casting is *cheap*. You're writing a UI application. UI is expensive. You're not going to notice any cost

Comment: @canton7 Well, true.

Comment: @JCode - You can't avoid casting. But casting is one of the fastest possible operations because it's pretty much done as compile time. And where possible the compiler optimizes it out.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this is not as hard as the comments make out.

Does this kind of thing work?

```
void Main()
{
    var mv = new ModelValidator();
    mv.AddValidator(new TagValidator());
    mv.AddValidator(new FooValidator());
    
    var tag = new Tag();
    
    mv.Validate(tag);
}

public class ModelValidator
{
    private List<object> _validators = new List<object>();
    
    public void AddValidator<T>(Validator<T> validator)
    {
        _validators.Add(validator); 
    }
    
    public void Validate<T>(T model)
    {
        foreach (Validator<T> validator in _validators.OfType<Validator<T>>())
        {
            validator.Validate(model);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Validator<T>
{
    public virtual void Validate(T model) { }
}

public class TagValidator : Validator<Tag> { }
public class FooValidator : Validator<Foo> { }

public class Tag { }
public class Foo { }
```