# How to declare a list of Action<T> that can manage differents generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, list, generics, delegates, polymorphism

I have a method that receives and action (previously was action < bool >, but now I need more types allowed):

```cs
public void Runaction<T>(Action<T> _ActionCallback)
{  
 StackAction.Add(_ActionCallback);
    ...etc
}
```

Previously, my list stackAction was:

```cs
readonly List<Action<bool>> StackAction=  new List<Action<bool>>()
```

But now I need this list to allowed type bool but byte[] too

When I declare

```cs
readonly List<Action<T>> StackAction=  new List<Action<T>>()
```

it returns T does not exists.

What is the workaround for this need?

Comment: If you declare the list in your method, it should work. Otherwise, you'll need to make your class generec: `class MyClass<T>`

Comment: Declare the entire class generic. But if you need a different types to handle, generics probably aren't the best solution

Comment: Do you expect to be able to add both types to the same list?

Comment: @Knoop Exactly!

Comment: Using `Action<object>` with casting may help

Comment: Sadly that's not something arbitrary. Generics are a way to enforce type safety across some generic functionality. What happens in your scenario of `Action<bool>` and `Action<byte[]>` is that behind the scenes the compiler generates 2 different classes. To work you ned to create some common point. But what exactly do you hope to achieve? `Action<bool>` is an action that must be called with a `bool` parameter so no point in mixing those with `Action<byte[]>` (which you can't call with a `bool`). If you really want to store them in the same list you could create a `List<delegate>` and then cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no diamond operator `<>` in C# and .NET does not support true generic polymorphism on open types yet.

[Generics open and closed constructed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

Thus we can't write:

```
readonly List<Action<>> StackAction = new List<Action<>>();
```

To allow a list of action of any one type parameter.

Moreover, this case of true generic polymorphism on delegates is more complicated to manage compared to classes or interfaces or value types.

But you can manage each type you want like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly List<object> StackAction = new List<object>();

  public void Runaction<T>(Action<T> _ActionCallback)
  {
    switch ( _ActionCallback )
    {
      case Action<bool> action:
        StackAction.Add(action);
        action(GetBoolParameter());
        break;
      case Action<byte[]> action:
        StackAction.Add(action);
        action(GetByteArrayParameter());
        break;
      default:
        string message = $"Type not supported for Runaction<T>." + Environment.NewLine
                       + $"Only bool or byte[] is allowed." + Environment.NewLine
                       + $"Type provided: {typeof(T).Name}";
        throw new ArgumentException(message);
    }
  }

  private bool GetBoolParameter()
  {
    return false;
  }

  private byte[] GetByteArrayParameter()
  {
    return new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  }
}
```

*Test*

```
Action<bool> actionBool = value =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
};
Action<byte[]> actionByteArray = value =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
};
Action<int> actionInt = value =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
};

var instance = new MyClass();

instance.Runaction(actionBool);
instance.Runaction(actionByteArray);

try
{
  instance.Runaction(actionInt);
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

*Output*

```
System.Boolean
System.Byte[]

Type not supported for Runaction<T>.
Only bool or byte[] is allowed.
Type provided: Int32
```

Answer (score -1):

Given this requirement the OP, that he needs to be able to store disparate types in the same list (`byte[]` and `bool`), there are three main ways to do this.

First, use `object` polymorphism and  declare your collection of that type. This of course makes it more difficult to use, because you have to test every type by hand yourself, and access it accordingly.

Second, similar to the first, use `dynamic`. This won't use polymorphism, it'll instantiate a compiler site to deal with the correct types as needed. This is better if you have some kind of duck typing, otherwise you'll have to try to cast it as #1, so you won't gain anything, and lose Intellisense in the process.

Third, and this is the least code smelly way, create a `struct` that contains both a `byte[]` and a `bool` property, and assign your data to one of the two, then you pass your structure to the action. There's no more casting attempts, just checking if individual properties are `null` or not. This is more akin to the C++ `std::any<>`.