# Casting from one user defined class to another with return problems. (C#)

Tags: c#, casting

I'm new to C#, and this doesn't make a whole lot of sense.
I'm converting a very simple class called User into another fairly simple class called InputCapsule.
The problem I'm getting is the when returning the input capsule, VS says the following.

> A user defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type.

I am quite confused, as I am returning the correct type.
My code for reference:

(The Name, Email, and Pass are properties if that changes things.)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello
{
    public class InputCapsule<T>
    {
        public static explicit operator InputCapsule<string>(User v)
        {
            InputCapsule<string> @out = new InputCapsule<string>();
            @out.inputs.Add(v.Name);
            @out.inputs.Add(v.Email);
            @out.inputs.Add(v.Pass);
            return @out;
        }
        public List<T> inputs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is converting to an `InputCapsule<string>` not an `InputCapsule<T>`.  The enclosing type is the `public class InputCapsule<T>`.

Comment: _"I am returning the correct type"_ -- no, you're not. The error message explains exactly what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for the "cast in (current type)" (I don't if this expression exist), you can't use a closed constructed generic type as a generic type parameter for the "name" of the explicit operator because the method definition is for open types (sorry if I don't use the good words).

Here you are not using the generic "method", you're defining it, because it takes a parameter being of type another than an `InputCapsule<>` (see @Sweeper answer about that I will call a "cast out (of current type)").

Thus here this generic type parameter `T` must be the same as the class itself as in `InputCapsule<T>`.

Therefore you can next check if `T` is string in the method body to allow or disallow (throw exception) the cast, or do anything else relevant.

You can for example write:

```
public class InputCapsule<T>
{
  public static explicit operator InputCapsule<T>(User v)
  {
    if ( typeof(T) == typeof(string) )
    {
      InputCapsule<string> instance = new InputCapsule<string>();
      instance.inputs.Add(v.Name);
      instance.inputs.Add(v.Email);
      instance.inputs.Add(v.Pass);
      return (InputCapsule<T>)(object)instance;
    }
    else
      throw new InvalidCastException();
  }
  public List<T> inputs = new List<T>();
}

public class User
{
  public string Name;
  public string Email;
  public string Pass;
}
```

To return the good type we use bosing and unboxing.

So you can implement any type conversion you need:

```
if ( typeof(T) == typeof(string) )
{
}
else
if ( typeof(T) == typeof(int) )
{
}
else
if ( typeof(T) == typeof(MyClass) )
{
}
else
  throw new InvalidCastException();
```

Also using the new switch pattern matching...

*Test*

```
  var user = new User { Name = "name", Email = "mail@mail.com", Pass = "pwd" };

  var inputcapsule = (InputCapsule<string>)user;

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inputcapsule.inputs));
```

*Output*

```html
name
mail@mail.com
pwd
```

[User-defined conversion operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

[What exactly is an "open generic type" in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net)

[Generics open and closed constructed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

[Open and Closed Generic Types in C#](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/open-and-closed-generic-types-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Either the source type or the destination type of the conversion operator must be the same as the type of the enclosing class/struct. Here, the enclosing class is `InputCapsule<T>`. Note that this is an open type. The destination type is `InputCapsule<string>` - a closed type. C# treats these very differently and considers them to be different types, even though they both start with `InputCapsule`. See [open and closed types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#open-and-closed-types).

Just to demonstrate that they are indeed different types, I can declare a conversion from `InputCapsule<T>` to `InputCapsule<string>`:

```
public static explicit operator InputCapsule<string>(InputCapsule<T> v)
{
    return null;
}
```

If they are the same type, this would not be permitted according to the [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#conversion-operators).

If you can change `User`, you should declare the conversion in `User` instead.