# Why does this code replace float with long?

Tags: c#, generics, types, instance, inner-classes

I have this code as an example:

```
class A<T> {
    public class B : A<long> {
        public void f() {
            Console.WriteLine( typeof(T).ToString());
        }
 
    public class C : A<long>.B { }
    
    } 
}

class Prg5 { static void Main() {
    var c = new A<float>.B.C();
    c.f();
} }
```

With output:

```
System.Int64
```

Why does it print the type for long? How and where does the float type passed originally get replaced?

Comment: Because `B` **is** an `A<long>`?

Comment: so is using float in "new A<float>.B() irrelevant? Could any type be put in and just be replaced with long? Shouldn't that return some error?

Comment: Seems weird to me also. I would expect `new A.B.C()` to work as well, but apparently it does not.

Comment: I agree, it isn't obvious.

Comment: To simplify things: you don´t even need `C` and also `B` has not to inherit `A`. It´s enough to nest `B` within a generic class to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `C` is an `A<long>.B` so `T` inside `f()` is `long`. The `float` in `new A<float>.B.C()` is not used.

Comment: I see, so the type of A is just dropped. Thank you all.

Comment: Sorry if I missed some convention, I'm not sure why the question was voted down when it's asking to clear up a confusing example and at least two other people agreed that it was confusing.

@OlivierRogier I'm not trying to output anything different, I just wanted to understand why it acts the way it does. Should I still delete it?

Comment: @OlivierRogier just omit all the method clunky stuff and the inheritance. Just imagine it was a generic class containing a non-generic one. To instantiate the latter, you´d need to provide the genric argument of the outer one, even if that argument is of no use within the nested class.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I would close the question but I don't have the rep yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `C` is defined as:

```
public class C : A<long>.B { }
```

The type `A` is defined as:

```
class A<T> {
    public class B : A<long> {
        public void f() {
            Console.WriteLine( typeof(T).ToString());
        }    

    public class C : A<long>.B { }
    } 
}
```

So if you create a new `C` then the type parameter for `A` is `long`.

In the statement `var c = new A<float>.B.C();`, `A<float>` and `B` are just parts of the "path" to the nested class `C`. The fact that `A<float>` is part of that path does not change the fact that `C` is an `A<long>.B`.

The `float` parameter and the fact that `B` is an `A<long>` are not relevant to determine the type of `T` inside `c.f()`.

Comment: "are just parts of the "path" to the nested class C" That´s the actual answer, IMHO.

Comment: I see, so it just needs "anything" since the parent class is generic. I could use `A<List<string>>.B.C()` and it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Yes and `B` can be an `A<StringBuilder>`. The fact that `C` is an `A<long>.B` determines the type of `T` in `c.f()`.

Comment: What's weird is that if `C` **does not** inherit from `B` and has it's own `f()`, then it returns "Single". The MSIL is exactly the same: `ldtoken     A<>.T`

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

When you call `f`, you are in a `A<T>` where `T` is `long` because `B` is a `A<long>` so `T` is `long`.

I see why it seems to be weird: you expect that `T` is `float`, but in fact since `B` is `A<long>`, `B` is a `A<T>` where `T` is `long`.

And because `C` is a child of `B`, it is an extended same type of `B` so a `A<long>`.

Therefore the result for the closed constructed type that output `long` and not `float` that was specified for the generic type parameter of the outer class.

So whatever the `T` specified when creating an instance, you will always get `long` for the type of `T` in `f`.

**Solving**

It's a little complicated recursive innering, I think, but don't you just simply need that?

```
class A<T>
{
  public class B : A<T>
  {
    public void f()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).ToString());
    }

    public class C : B { }

  }
}
```

Thus writing:

```
var c = new A<float>.B.C();
c.f();
```

Will output:

```
System.Single
```

**Readings**

[Generics open and closed constructed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)

[Constructed Types](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1648574&seqNum=4)

[Generics in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/)

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

[C# Generics Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm)

[C# Generics Level 2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics)

Comment: I'm not looking to change anything, I just want to understand why it outputs "System.Int64" as it does.